# How to get multiple network interface cards data

Tags: c#, nic

I have code, which find my NIC card IP address, IP subnet, Gateway, Mac and network card name (description). But the problem is, I have multiple NIC cards and WiFi on my PC. And this program instead of 4 NIC cards  shows me only one primary.
How can solve this problem ?

```
public  void NIC_data()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher query = new
        ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
        {
            string[] addresses = (string[])mo["IPAddress"];
            string[] subnets = (string[])mo["IPSubnet"];
            string[] defaultgateways = (string[])mo["DefaultIPGateway"];
            textBox1.Text = string.Format("Network Card: {0}", mo["Description"]);
            textBox2.Text = string.Format(" MAC Address: {0}", mo["MACAddress"]);
            foreach (string ipaddress in addresses)
            {
                textBox3.Text = string.Format(" IP Address: {0}", ipaddress);
            }
            foreach (string subnet in subnets)
            {
                textBox4.Text = string.Format(" Subnet Mask: {0}", subnet);
            }
            foreach (string defaultgateway in defaultgateways)
            {
                textBox5.Text = string.Format(" Gateway: {0}", defaultgateway);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you get all network adapter configuration if you change your query to SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration?

Comment: @Hans , in simply list , i get all cards !

Comment: Aren't you replacing the text in the textbox each time you update it in the loop? So you will only be displaying one from each category at any time, since it overwrites the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

You just assign the last value of the loop to textBoxes like `textBox3.Text = ....`.

either append to `textBox3.Text +=  ...` or use a combo box.